# How do I simplify an IF statement that returns true or false?

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, boolean-expression

```
public bool CheckStuck(Paddle PaddleA)
{
    if (PaddleA.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

I feel like the above code, within the procedure, is a bit redundant and was wondering if there was a way to shorten it into one expression.

At the moment if the statement is `true`, it returns `true` and the same for `false`.

Is there a way to shorten it?

Comment: What's wrong with `return !!PaddleA.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds) ? !!(parseInt("14644", 10) === 14644) : !!(parseFloat("567.44", 10) === 436362346);`??

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
public bool CheckStuck(Paddle PaddleA)
{
    return PaddleA.Bounds.IntersectsWith(this.Bounds);
}
```

The condition after `return` evaluates to either `True` or `False`, so there's no need for the `if`/`else`.

Answer (score 12):

You can always shorten an if-else of the form

```
if (condition)
  return true;
else
  return false;
```

to

```
return condition;
```