# incorrect variable declaration? or erratic modulo behavior?

Tags: javascript, modulo

why, in the following code, does modB always equal 1? ESPECIALLY considering b % 2 doesn't?

```
var b = 0;
var modB = 0;
function buttonState() {
            b++;
            modB = b % 2;
            if (modB = 1) {
                theButtonState = true;
            } else {
                theButtonState = false;
             }
             console.log(b%2);
             console.log(modB);
             console.log(theButtonState);
        }
```

Comment: Because you are setting it to `1`: `if (modB = 1) {`. Also, please don't write `if` statements that just set a boolean value. Just do `theButtonState = modB === 1;`.

Comment: Thanks @FelixKling! I changed that line to `code` if (modB < 1) {  then switched the true and false. How would I find out if modB is = 1?

Comment: Use the [comparison operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Comparison_operators) `===` (or `==` if you prefer loose comparison, which you should not). I'm curious, why did you think that `=` would behave differently in `modB = b % 2;` or `theButtonState = true;` vs `if (modB = 1) {` ?

Comment: Most linters will warn about that mistake. I particularly use for my personal projects http://www.javascriptlint.com/, for small cases you could use an online version like http://www.javascriptlint.com/online_lint.php,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line of code:

```
if (modB = 1)
```

to

```
if (modB == 1)
```

and then try running the program again.

You can do it this way too as (Felix explained):

```
theButtonState = modB == 1;
```

Brevity in code improves its readability immensely.

Comment: Or even better: `theButtonState = modB === 1;`.

Comment: `theButtonState = modB == 1 ? true : false;`  => serious?

Comment: @FelixKling I agree, that is better. I will add that as an alternative.

Comment: It's like writing:  `x = 1 + 2 - 1 - 1` instead of `x = 1` ;)

Comment: @codehitman http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320961/how-do-i-simplify-an-if-statement-that-returns-true-or-false