# Filter by the number of digits pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `Dataframe` that has only one column with numbers ranging from 1 to 10000000000.

```
    df1 = 
165437890
2321434256
324334567
4326457
243567869
234567843
 ......
7654356785432
7654324567543
```

I want to have a resulting `Dataframe` that only has numbers with 9 digits, and that those digits are different from each other, is this possible ? I don't have a clue on how to start

OBS: 
1) I need to filter out the number that has repeated digits

for example :

`122234543` would go out of my `DataFrame` since it has the number `2` repeated 3 times and  the numbers `4` and `3` repeated 2 times

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_good(num):
    numstr = list(str(num))
    if len(numstr) == 9 and len(set(numstr))==9:
       return True
    return False

    df1[df.apply(is_good)]
```

Comment: @ggorlen I think the OP wants there to be nine digits, AND the digits to be distinct, so you do need two tests.

Comment: Yep, you're right. I missed that. Nonetheless, the `list` call and `if ... return True / return False` can be eliminated, anyway.

Comment: @ggorlen True. for the last, I wanted to make it as clear as possible to the OP...

Comment: That's well-intentioned, but I think this pattern actually [harms readability](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17320961/how-do-i-simplify-an-if-statement-that-returns-true-or-false).

Comment: Please edit your answer to explain how it answers the question.

Comment: I would actually argue, that it's the only answer, which does answer the question - 9 unique digits is the condition, and not 9 digits and unique combinations. +1 from me

Answer (score 2):

```
flt = (df.Numbers >= 100000000) & (df.Numbers < 1000000000)
df = pd.DataFrame(df[flt]['Numbers'].unique())
```

Where `Numbers` is the column name with your numbers.

---

Solution for digits that are different from each other in the number itself:

```
df.Numbers = df.Numbers.astype('str')
df = df[df.Numbers.str.match(r'^(?!.*(.).*\1)[0-9]{9}$')]
```

---

Or another solution based on the Igor's answer:

```
def has_unique_9digits(n):
    s = str(n)
    return len(s) == len(set(s)) == 9
df = df[df.Numbers.apply(has_unique_9digits)]
```

Comment: You could also do `df.loc[flt, 'Numbers'].drop_duplicates()` instead of reconstructing the DataFrame.

Comment: `numbers with 9 digits, and that those digits are different from each other`

Comment: sorry for the delay. in fact, I need as Skibinski pointed out, to sort out the digits that are different from each other in the number itself

Comment: Then you have to change the type to 'str' and use the RegEx. You may add '.astype(int) at the and to change it back to numbers.