# fs module in node js fs.existsSync not recognising with Latin filename

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node.js-fs

I have some file names in "LATIN" but the fs.existsSync function is not able to recognise it

`1689017335025-Naan En Nesarudaiyavan â mix.json`

I tired with buffer too but still not able to get the proper response.

I am providing the proper path of the file too but still its not detecting that file.

I am using the fs module in electron js.

Other files other than Latin are been properly detected by `fs.existsSync`

```
const localDownloadPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), ${endpath}/${detail.name});
if(fs.existsSync(localDownloadPath)){ 
   return true; 
}else {return false;}
```

Comment: const localDownloadPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), `${endpath}/${detail.name}`)
if(fs.existsSync(localDownloadPath)){
   return true;
}else {return false;}

Comment: Edit your question with the code

Comment: Are you sure the file path `localDownloadPath` is correct?

Comment: Yes other files with non latin filename are detected but only the latin file names are not detected

Comment: Unrelated but useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17321000/4554883

Answer (score 0):

As said in Node.js [docs](https://nodejs.org/dist/v18.16.0/docs/api/fs.html#fsexistspath-callback),

> Using `fs.exists()` to check for the existence of a file before calling `fs.open()`, `fs.readFile()`, or `fs.writeFile()` is not recommended. Doing so introduces a rare condition, since other processes may change the file's state between the two calls. Instead, user code should open/read/write the file directly and handle the error raised if the file does not exist.

So if you want to read/open a file, rather call the function and catch errors.

Example of `fs.readFile()`:

```js
const fs = require('node:fs');

let fd;

fs.readFile('myFile.txt','r',(err, data) => {
  if(err) {
    if(err.code == 'ENOENT') {
      console.error('myFile.txt does not exist');
      return;
    }
    throw err;
  }
  fd = data;
});
```

---

*PS:*
I tried what you described in question as not working for you and it works well for me. Check if you wrote that filename correctly.
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLsz.png)

Comment: Tried but still not working

Comment: @HenilMehta try to replace `${endpath}/${detail.name}` in **your** code with `endpath,"/",detail.name`

Comment: @HenilMehta Are you sure `app.getPath('userData')` function in **your** code returns a valid path? Because `fs.existSync` never throws error - you can even pass to function random symbols and it just returns `false`.